# Java char array to int

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert a `char[]` array containing numbers into
an `int`?

Answer (score 28):

Does the `char[]` contain the unicode characters making up the digits of the number? In that case simply create a String from the `char[]` and use Integer.parseInt:

```
char[] digits = { '1', '2', '3' };
int number = Integer.parseInt(new String(digits));
```

Comment: Starting with Java 9, you can use `Integer.parseInt(CharBuffer.wrap(digits),0,digits.length, 10)` which avoids copying the array.

Answer (score 11):

Even more performance and cleaner code (and no need to allocate a new String object):

```
int charArrayToInt(char []data,int start,int end) throws NumberFormatException
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        int digit = (int)data[i] - (int)'0';
        if ((digit < 0) || (digit > 9)) throw new NumberFormatException();
        result *= 10;
        result += digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast `char` to `int`. And `result *= 10; result += digit;` is not better than a straight-forward `result = result * 10 + digit;`

Comment: How about `-1`?

Answer (score 8):

```
char[] digits = { '0', '1', '2' };
int number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(digits));
```

This also works.

Comment: This will not work if char array is long e.g. 1534236469 . You need to user Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(digits))

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to convert a `char[]` array containing numbers into an `int`. You can use following different implementation to convert array.

1. Using `Integer.parseInt`

   ```
   public static int charArrayToInteger(char[] array){
       String arr = new String(array);
       int number = Integer.parseInt(arr);

       return number;
   }
   ```
2. Without `Integer.parseInt`

   ```
   public static int charArrayToInt(char[] array){
       int result = 0;
       int length = array.length - 1;

       for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
       {
            int digit = array[i] - '0'; //we don't want to cast by using (int)
            result *= 10;
            result += digit;
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

Example:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    char[] array = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
    int result = 0;

    result = charArrayToInteger(array);
    System.out.println("Using Integer.parseInt: " + result);

    result = charArrayToInt(array);
    System.out.println("Without Integer.parseInt: " + result);

 }
```

Output:

```
Using Integer.parseInt: 12345
Without Integer.parseInt: 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with more performance:

```
char[] digits = { '1', '2', '3' };

int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
   int digit = ((int)chars[i] & 0xF);
   for (int j = 0; j < chars.length-1-i; j++) {
        digit *= 10;
   }
   result += digit;
}
```

Comment: You can simply replace your inner loop with `result *= 10;`.

Comment: Do you mean replace `digit *= 10;` to `result *= 10;` ?

Comment: No, you can get rid of the *entire* inner loop (`for (int j = ...`) and replace all three lines with just `result *= 10;`.

Comment: 1. chars[i] -'0' is faster than  chars[i] & 0xF
2.you can replace the inner for loop  to result*=10;

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try even this

```
    char c[] = {'1','2','3'};
    int total=0,x=0,m=1;
    for(int i=c.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        x = c[i] - '0';
        x = x*m;
        m *= 10;
        total += x;
    }
    System.out.println("Integer is " + total);
```