# Java: Problems converting char to int

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java char array to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683324/java-char-array-to-int)

I have the following code, where `stackCells` is an `ArrayList` object:

```
int[] stackCell = {0, 0};

if (!stackCells.isEmpty())  {
    String stackCellString = stackCells.get(0);
    stackCell[0] = stackCellString.charAt(0);
    stackCell[1] = stackCellString.charAt(1);
}
```

So the problem I am encountering is that `stackCell` is not interpreting the character as an `int`. For example, the value of `stackCellString` should be `"88"`. However, when I use `chartAt(0)` and `charAt(1)`, I get an int value of `56`. If I use those same calls inside a `System.out.println(stackCellString.charAt(0) + stackCellString.charAt(1))` command, I get the correct result (i.e. `"88"`).

Comment: what is `stackCellString`

Comment: @Woot4Moo I have it written in the paragraph.

Comment: @KarthikT But I thought a `char` can be used as an `int` without casting. I tried casting too, with no luck.

Comment: why are you using an int array? if you are trying to store chars?

Comment: @SeanF I need to store the index of a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

56 is the ASCII code of the digit 8. To get what you want, you could do this:

```
stackCell[0] = stackCellString.charAt(0) - '0';
stackCell[1] = stackCellString.charAt(1) - '0';
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Nothing simpler.

Comment: The simpler solution is to not pass around strings knowing you have to convert them later.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Sure, but I have no choice. The code given does not give the context of my program, so I can understand why you may find my approach confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It's interpreting the character as an int in the following way:

`56` is the ASCII code for the character `'8'`.

If you want to grab the numeric digits from the string, you will need to use something like `Integer.parseInt()` as one of the comments mentioned.

A more efficient solution might be to do some math based on the ASCII code.  If you know all of the characters are decimal digits, you could do `(code - 48)` to get the digit (where `code` is the ASCII code).  For instance, `(56 - 48) = 8`, which is what you want here.

Comment: doing parseInt is very expensive.

Comment: True.  Alternatively, you could compute the digit based on the ASCII code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ft1 answered with that idea first, so I'm giving this one to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

```
String stackCellString="88";
        stackCell[0] = stackCellString.charAt(0);
        stackCell[1] = stackCellString.charAt(1);
        System.out.println(stackCell[0]);
        System.out.println(stackCell[1]);
        System.out.println(stackCell[0]+stackCell[1]);
        System.out.println(stackCellString.charAt(0) + stackCellString.charAt(1));
```

output:

```
56
56
112
112
```

You are not returning the `charAt` as its character representation.

If you want it to return "88" you need to do this:

```
stackCellString.subString(0,1) + stackCellString.subString(1,2);
```

Another work around is this:

```
"" + stackCellString.charAt(0) + stackCellString.charAt(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. But what am I returning it as my way, if not the character representation?

Comment: @capcom you are returning the short value of the character.

Comment: Is there an 'inexpensive' way to get what I want? I need the 8s as integer values, not substrings.

Comment: @capcom the least expensive way is to not convert from a String to an Int.  Make your ArrayList one of Integers.  If that is not practical then you will need to eat the conversion cost of String to Integer

Comment: Check out ft1's solution above. It works great, and is anything but expensive.

Comment: @capcom I saw it, once again the least expensive way is to not pass around Strings in the first place.