# Java read integer from middle of the string

Tags: java, android, string, integer

Is it possible in Java to **efficiently** read an integer from random position of the string? For instance, I have a

```
String s = "(34";
if (s.charAt(0) == '(')
{
    // How to read a number from position = 1 to the end of the string?
    // Of course, I can do something like
    String s1 = s.substring(1);
    int val = Integer.parseInt(s1);
}
```

but it dynamically creates a new instance of string and seems to be too slow and performance hitting.

**UPDATE**

Well, to be precise: I have an array of strings in form "(ddd" where d is a digit. So I do know that a number starts always from pos = 1. How do I efficently read these numbers?

Comment: @Nick Please apply more examples of `source data` and `results` you want to get

Comment: Read into a StringBuilder object in the first place, atleast that'll save you the overheads of creating a new string object everytime.

Comment: First, thank you all. I have updated my question to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered after the update:**

`String` is a final object, you cannot edit it, so if you want to get some `digit` value from it, you have the 2 ways:

**1.** Use your code, that will work fine, but if you care about performance, try `2nd` way.

**2.** Divide your string on digits and add them to get the result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "(123456";

    if(input.charAt(0) == '(') {
        System.out.println(getDigit(input));
    }
}

private static int getDigit(String s) {
    int result = 0;
    int increase = 10;

    for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int digit = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
        result*=increase;
        result += digit;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
123456
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answered before the update:**

I'm not an expert in regex, but hope this `"\\d+"` is useful to you. Invoke the below method with pattern:  ***`"\\d+"`***.

```
public static int returnInt(String pattern,String inputString){
    Pattern intPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = intPattern.matcher(inputString);
    matcher.find();
    String input = matcher.group();
    return Integer.parseInt(input);
}
```

Comment: This certainly won't be faster than a hardcoded `substring` operation. It might be equivalent if you mentioned that the `Pattern` and `Matcher` must be reused for optimal performance but as it stands it is orders of magnitude slower. And if the OP is worried that the code in the question "dynamically creates a new instance of string" then regex is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: *hardcoded substring operation* : But the position of the `int` is random as posted by OP!

Comment: "How to read a number from position = 1 to the end of the string" - I think that is the question. Where position can vary but _is known_.

Comment: The first line : *Is it possible in Java to **efficiently** read an integer from **random** position of the string.*

Comment: First, thank you all. I have updated my question to be clear. I always read from pos = 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt(s1.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""))
```

Comment: That still creates a new String object. String objects are immutable and applying any manipulation function would result in the creation of a new String. So, you aren't really giving a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allocate a new `String` then you can use the code in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297485/2071828):

```
int charArrayToInt(char[] data, int start, int end) throws NumberFormatException {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        int digit = ((int)data[i] & 0xF);
        if ((digit < 0) || (digit > 9)) throw new NumberFormatException();
        result *= 10;
        result += digit;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can call it with `charArrayToInt(s.toCharArray(), 1, s.length())`

Comment: Will not s.toCharArray() allocate a memory to create a char[] object? If it will, where is a performance boost comparing to s.substring(1)?

Comment: It will, yes. But it doesn't need to declare the whole enclosing `String` object. Also, have your ever looked at the code for `Integer.parseInt`? Because it's robust to input errors and can parse negative number etc it's very complex - this parsing code is much simpler.

Comment: @Nick a quick benchmark of 10,000,000 iterations shows that the `charArrayToInt` method is about twice the speed of the `parseInt` and `substring` method.

Comment: Oh, I appreciate your efforts. Thank you. However, I guess the accepted answer is even faster.