# Java: how to output double-type number to integer format if its decimal is 0

Tags: java, numbers

I have an array of double-type numbers {1.0, 2.3, 3.45, 7.8, 9.0, 5.0}. When outputting the numbers, I want to have those with decimal of 0 to show up like an integer: for example, 1.0 => 1, 9.0 => 9.

In java, how do you do this easily? thanks

Comment: Look up the `NumberFormat` class.

Comment: `DecimalFormat` or if it's console `System.printf()` like in c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683324/java-char-array-to-int  Try this link to a question asked before

Comment: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); df.parse(3.0D)`;

Comment: @nachokk An alternate to `System.printf()` for non-console stuff is `String.format()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not using any libraries I'd suggest:

```
public static String parse(double num) {
    if((int) num == num) return Integer.toString((int) num); //for you, StackOverflowException
    return String.valueOf(num); //and for you, Christian Kuetbach
}
```

Casting a double to int will cut off decimal places.

Feel free to convert the number to a string in whatever way you please ;)

Comment: Would you please use [Integer.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int))? In my opinion it's better style than ""+anything...

Comment: I would use String.valueOf() :)

Comment: Or that one, but String.valueOf calls Integer.toString internally, so it's one method call less. Not worth worrying about though...