# How do I convert a char [] to an int?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a problem where I need to take an array of chars (composed solely of digits) and print out it's value as an integer.

```
public static int ParseInt(char [] c) {
    //convert to an int
    return int;
}
```

The array would look something like this:

```
char [] c = {'3', '5', '9', '3'}
```

And would give an output of:

```
3593
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java char array to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683324/java-char-array-to-int)

Comment: please accept one of the answer below so that other having same problem can find the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char[] c = {'3', '5', '9', '3'};
int number = Integer.parseInt(new String(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way way would be -

```
public static int ParseInt(char [] c) {
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<c.length;i++) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c[i]));
        temp = temp * 10 + value;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: And I'd it were to turn out they can't use the String class for some reason, one can also do `int value = c[i] - '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good or standard approach but you can use it as other solution.In below code `Arrays.toString(c)` convert character array to string and then replace `[],'` with blank then typecast string to int.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        char [] c = {'3', '5', '9', '3'};
        String n=Arrays.toString(c).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","").replace("'","").replace(" ","");
        int k=Integer.parseInt(n);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
```

#### DEMO

Comment: That is a truly vile way to convert a char array to a string... :)

Comment: @AndyTurner just trying to give a different way of doing that instead of iterating over each array element.This is certainly take less time then iterating over each element.

Comment: I know, that was the reason for the :)

Comment: Can you explain further, @singhakash? `Arrays.toString()` iterates over each element of the array to create the string, and then each `replace` iterates over each element of the char array backing the corresponding string. If I'm not misunderstanding something, this way of doing it iterates over each element of at least six different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Character.getNumericValue()` function

```
public static int ParseInt(char [] c) {
    int retValue = 0;
    int positionWeight = 1;
    for(int i=c.lenght-1; i>=0; i--){
        retValue += Character.getNumericValue(c[i]) * positionWeight;
        positionWeight += 10;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

Pay attention to the fact that I start form `length-1` and I loop until 0 (according to the positional weight convention).

Answer (score 0):

Because it contains only digits. Hence, we can solve like this:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
    result = result * 10 + (c[i] - '0');
}
return result;
```

I hope it helps.