# Is there a faster way to parse a string for valid integers in Java?

Tags: json, regex, string, performance, java-8

My application is expecting json requests containing a (possible multi-dimensional) unsorted array with only integers and possible null values. Something like `[6, 2, [4, 3],[[[5], nil], 1]]`

Since I can't parse the invalid json, I've had to resort to using a regex to do the dirty work, and it is super slow.

The test case above for example takes about `1.xx seconds` to complete, while a flat array with `10000` elements takes less than `1 second`

Currently I'm getting the request body as a string and then applying the regex.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> getIntegers(String requestData) {
    // Apply a regex to the request body
    final String regularExpression = "([^\\d])+";
    // to get all the nested arrays
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
    String[] results = pattern.split(requestData);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    // loop over the results and add to numbers array
    for (String result : results) {
        try {
            numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(result));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Catch and skip any non integers
        }

    }
    return numbers;
}
```

}

Is there anyway I can speed this up or is there maybe an alternative approach with better performance? If I need to process a multi-dimensional array with 20000 elements it will be way too slow.

Comment: Nice question!! If this were javascript, I would have asked you to try .flatmap(Infinite) and then checking. Maybe this will give some ideas.

Comment: @AdityaGupta thanks for the tip! Will definitely research your suggestion for some ideas

Comment: Why are you attempting to parse invalid JSON instead of simply rejecting such requests?

Comment: small side note, the regex `[^\d]` is equal to `\D`, both will match everything except numbers

Comment: @SalmanA my requirement is to remove the `nil` values and get only valid integers. If I could simply reject the request that would be great. This is not a production system, if it was then your question and advice would be spot on (and exactly what I was thinking myself)

Comment: @krankit if it is just the `nil` then replace them with `null` using string replace. You will end up with valid JSON which you could parse with any JSON parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105020/2711488) does already point into the right direction. The first important step is to move the expensive `Pattern.compile` operation out of the method, as `Pattern` instance can be reused.

Further, iterating over the number matches saves you from the array creation of `split`. Now, you may also skip the sub-`String` creation:

```
static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
static ArrayList<Integer> getIntegers(String requestData) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = NUMBER.matcher(requestData);
    while(m.find()) numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(requestData, m.start(), m.end(), 10));
    return numbers;
}
```

`Integer.parseInt(CharSequence s, int beginIndex, int endIndex, int radix)` has been added in Java 9. If you are operating at an older version, you may create your own variant of it. For simplification, now only supporting a radix of 10:

```
static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
static ArrayList<Integer> getIntegers(String requestData) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = NUMBER.matcher(requestData);
    while(m.find()) numbers.add(parseInt(requestData, m.start(), m.end()));
    return numbers;
}

static int parseInt(CharSequence cs, int start, int end) {
    int pos = start;
    if(pos >= end) throw format(cs, start, end);
    boolean negative = cs.charAt(pos) == '-';
    if((negative || cs.charAt(pos) == '+') && ++pos==end)
        throw format(cs, start, end);
    int value = 0;
    for(; pos < end; pos++) {
        int next = cs.charAt(pos) - '0';
        if(next < 0 || next > 9) throw format(cs, start, end);
        if(value < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10) throw size(cs, start, pos, end);
        value = value * 10 - next;
    }
    if(value > 0 || !negative && value == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        throw size(cs, start, pos, end);
    return negative? value: -value;
}
private static RuntimeException format(CharSequence cs, int start, int end) {
    return start > end? new IndexOutOfBoundsException(end+" < "+start):
        new NumberFormatException(start == end?
            "empty string": cs.subSequence(start, end).toString());
}
private static RuntimeException size(CharSequence cs, int start, int pos, int end) {
    for(; pos < end; pos++) 
        if(cs.charAt(pos) < '0' || cs.charAt(pos) > '9') return format(cs, start, end);
    return new NumberFormatException(cs.subSequence(start, end)+" outside the int range");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've tinkered around a bit and created following class:

```
class JsonNumberParser {
    private final String json;
    private final int length;
    private final List<Integer> result;
    private final char[] buffer = new char[64];
    private int bufferIndex = 0;

    public JsonNumberParser(String json) {
        this.json = json;
        length = json.length();
        result = new ArrayList<>(length);
    }

    public List<Integer> parse() {
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            c = json.charAt(i);
            // if we encounter a comma and the buffer contains data
            if (c == ',' && bufferIndex > 0) {
                // then we add the new number
                addBuffer();
                // and reset the buffer
                while (bufferIndex > 0) {
                    buffer[--bufferIndex] = '\0';
                }
            } else if (c == '-' || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
                buffer[bufferIndex++] = c;
            }
        }
        // add the last possible number, if there was any
        if (bufferIndex > 0) {
            addBuffer();
        }

        // return the result
        return result;
    }

    private void addBuffer() {
        result.add(Integer.valueOf(new String(buffer, 0, bufferIndex)));
    }
}
```

Of course you could put all of that into a single method, but then you'd get some code duplication regarding the adding of `Integers`.

The way this parser works is, that it uses a buffer, to buffer digits, until we encounter a comma. That way we can have big numbers (up to 64 digits in this implementation) in the json.

You can use this like shown in the following example:

```
List<Integer> integers = new JsonNumberParser(jsonRequest).parse();
```

Regarding the performance, I expect this to be much faster than using a `Regex`. But I sadly don't have a benchmark setup at hand

---

> Keep in mind, that this is not a validator, so a json string: `[[,,,]}]` would just produce an empty `List`

---

**(Maybe) Improvements**: I've thought and searched a bit more. Here are some improvements which *could* make the performance better:

**1.** One could just reset the `buffer` by assigning it with a `new int[64]`, which would produce more garbage, but in the end may be faster.

**2.** The parsing of the number could be improved by using the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297485/5515060). Which uses just plain old math and no creation of strings and parsing of integers.

Comment: Why resetting the array at all? You are only using the part you’ve overwritten with actual values, so dangling `char` values (unlike object references) are irrelevant. Just set `bufferIndex` to zero. But even better, instead of copying the `char` values to your own buffer array, you could simply remember the position of the first matching character and use `substring` on the original string when encountering either, the first non-matching character or the end of the string. Or use the `parseInt(CharSequence cs, int start, int end)` method of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is the issue in your case I don't think stream API will be a good solution.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> getIntegers(String requestData) {
            char[] charArray = requestData.toCharArray();
             ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
            for(char c : charArray) {

                if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(c) - 48);
                }
            }
            return numbers;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems the solution doesn't work with double (or triple) digit numbers since it gets formatted to a single `char` as you can see in my test case `SEVERE: java.lang.AssertionError: Not equals : [0,2,4,5,5,9,9] != [0,2,4,55,99]`

Comment: Also the wrapping of `Integer.valueOf(c)` seems to be unnecessary since you are already checking if the character is a digit with `Character.isDigit(c)`. Will play around with this later thanks!

Comment: Further, as explained in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096349/is-there-a-faster-way-to-parse-a-string-for-valid-integers-in-java/54111864#comment95056127_54105020), mixing `Character.isDigit(…)` with code handling only characters in the `'0' .. '9'` range is not a good idea. There’s also no reason to write `48` instead of the `'0'` character constant. Also, creating an entire copy of the string contents via `toCharArray()` just for the sake of writing a for-each loop, does not add to performance.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a stack?

We can upgrade [balanced braces](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/) problem.

While iterating the string, if the character is `notBracket()`, then it should be a number. Needless to say, you ignore all commas. Simultaneously, it will also verify the array structure.

This has an amortized complexity of `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain better performance by parsing positive patterns (e.g. `\d+`) instead of negative ones (`[^\d]+`).

```
private static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

List<Integer> extractNumbersRegex(String str) throws IOException {
    Matcher m = NUMBER.matcher(str);
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

This would be ok for extracting from strings, yet for large data one may switch to more efficient that do not depend on regular expressions but on directly matching chars:

```
List<Integer> extractNumbersHandcoded(String str) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = 0;
    while (start < str.length()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(start))) {
            break;
        } 
        start++;
    }
    int bufferedInt = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            bufferedInt = bufferedInt * 10 + (c - '0');
        } else {
            numbers.add(bufferedInt);
            bufferedInt = 0;
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

If your data is as large that it comes as stream you may consider a solution with a `Streamtokenizer`:

```
List<Integer> extractNumbersStreamTokenizer(String str) throws IOException {
    StreamTokenizer s = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(str));
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    int token;
    while ((token = s.nextToken()) != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
            numbers.add((int) s.nval);
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

All solutions assume that the data contains only integer literals (not float literals).

Comment: Keep in mind that `Character.isDigit(…)` may return `true` for characters outside the `'0' .. '9'` range. When you use `Character.isDigit(…)` to test, you should also use `Character.digit(…)` to extract. Otherwise, use an explicit test for the `'0' .. '9'` range when you only want to handle values of that range. Further, your code may overflow silently when the number’s magnitude is too large.